# VBA Save a String across submodule calls

Tags: vba, save, filepath

I am making an "intelligent save" button for word and excel files.
The first time it is run from a file, it will prompt user to navigate to the correct folder. The important part is **the selected path will be saved for that file and automatically referenced the next time someone uses the macro.** Then the user can specify pdf vs. docx/xlsx file type, then save the file.

**Is the bolded part possible, and what kind of technique/functions can I use to do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted as an answer, with a bit of example code and more detail:

For such a small amount of data, why not use VBA's SaveSetting/GetSetting commands to put the needed info in the registry?

```
Sub SaveGetSettingExample()

' Saves string values to:
' HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings\AppName

    SaveSetting "AppName", "Section", "Key", "Value"

    ' Displays the just-stored value:  Value
    MsgBox GetSetting("AppName", "Section", "Key", "Default Value")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're embedding the code in the workbook (and not in the Personal code folder).  If so, I've had success writing the file path to a cell in a hidden column (usually out to far right of view) in Excel.  Your code can reference this default location as needed when loading the next time.

I'm not sure about Word, our Word documents stay pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks, this was my thought, too. Unfortunately, I do need a place to store the file path in word. Perhaps a dummy variable that's in the docx file that can be reappropriated, or somewhere I can conveniently tuck the string. Worse comes to worse I will implement a database of some sort.

Comment: For such a small amount of data, why not use VBA's SaveSetting/GetSetting commands to put the needed info in the registry?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg If you submit this as an answer I will accept it as the solution.

Comment: Thank you @SteveRindsberg, I will need to look into the SaveSetting/GetSetting commands, much more sound approach than what I suggested.